# IFrame or WebResource for FileUpload for CRM 2013 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am pretty new to CRM, now I am trying to have a field in a form where any kind of file can be uploaded. I know it can be done by either a plugin, web resource or IFrame. I need to develop one of my own, I need some resource which might help to develop this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CRM has a built in ability to upload files and attach them to records. The entity they are stored in is called "annotation" and being a normal CRM entity you can do CRUD operations using the normal CRM web services.

I have developed a custom silverlight component that you can drop on a form that allows you to drag and drop files as well as place these files in folders